# Custom condition for Elastic search collection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, product-collection, elasticsearch

I am trying to add the custom condition for the product collection using the below plugin for elastic search.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
   <type name="Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch">
       <plugin name="elastcisearch_filter_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugins\ElasticLayerPlugin" />
   </type>
```

**Vendor\Module\Plugins\ElasticLayerPlugin.php**

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Plugins;
 class ElasticLayerPlugin
 {
   protected $helperObj;    
    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helperObj
    ) 
     {
       $this->helperObj = $helperObj;
     }

   public function beforeQuery($subject,$query) 
   {
      $filteredIds   = $this->helperObj->filterCollectionIds();
    
      if(!$filteredIds || count($filteredIds) < 1)  {
        return [$query]; 
      }

     // Add the product ids to filter the Elasticsearch product collection      
      $query['body']['query']['bool']['filter'] = ['ids' => [ 'values' => $filteredIds]];
      return [$query];
   }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
 public $listProductBlock;
  public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listProductBlock
) {       
    $this->listProductBlock  = $listProductBlock;     
    parent::__construct($context);
  }
public function filterCollectionIds(){
    $productCollection = $this->listProductBlock->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', array('eq' => "No"));
   $filteredIds = array();
    foreach($productCollection as $product){
        $productId = $product->getId();
       $filteredIds[] = $productId;
    }
    return $filteredIds;
  }

}
```

I am using custom layered navigation which is causing the count mismatch in the toolbar and filters. The above code not working for me.

how can we add the filter to the collection with a custom attribute?

Can anyone suggest this issue? Thanks

Comment: Make Sure to have reindexed all your indexers.

Comment: Reindex done, what is the correct answer for the issue?

Comment: you are using right way to achive this, I have used the same method and it working for me. can you check which ES version you are on?

Comment: Mine is elastic search 7.0

Comment: It's same Mine is also 7.0 and I have done the same thing and it's working fine for me.
double-check if your ES is indexing properly / your plugin is calling or not etc

Answer (score 0):

Look at this plug in and try with you filter condition.

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/custom-conditions-before-get-faceted-data-elastic-search-magento/

Comment: hello @rex, The above plugin is not working. I tried this before i am posting the question